# How to upgrade Outlook 2010 to 365 Custom User Properties

Tags: javascript, outlook, exchange-server, office365, office365-apps

We are looking to upgrade an Office 2010 C# add-in and part of the code saves data to the Extended properties that we then read server side from Exchange:

```cs
    item.UserProperties.Find("JobId", true).Value = "1234"
```

The Visual Studio 2013 Outlook 365 app appears to use the following.

```js
    _mailbox.item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(customPropsCallback);

    _customProps.set('JobId', $('#jobid').val());
    _customProps.saveAsync(saveCallback);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161021(v=office.15).aspx

How can I save directly to the Extended Properties from the 365 app? 
https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/Calendars('Calendar')/Events?$top=10 doesn't show them.

I don't think an EWS call will work as the appointment might not be saved yet.

Should I get the 365 properties server side then update the exchange item? This feels wrong.

Will I have to change my server side code to look from extended properties and custom properties?

Thanks

Comment: Have you had any resolution on this? I need to do something similar and am also at a bit of an impasse. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: No sorry. I've move projects and I don't think they have pushed for Office 365.